# iOS app "edit" link populates with incorrect revision

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app

I improved (from review) a suggested edit on [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/82109/52050), and after revisiting the question realised I missed something... no problem, I'll just edit the question again right? Apparently not.

This is the current state of the question (the result of my edit improvement):

> [image: current question state]

However when I hit the edit button I get this:

> [image: old version]

Which is wrong. It took me a minute to figure out that it's actually giving me the body of the edit that I improved (revision 2), when it should of course be giving me the most recent revision (revision 3).

> [image: old revision]
>
> [image: history]

I checked a few other "improved" edits and can't reproduce this on any other post so it's not (at least not *only*) a result of the improved edit. So, what's going on?

Comment: Caching. I always find on mobile that editing the same post multiple times doesn't work and ends up reloading the old version unless I remember to explicitly refresh the page after clicking the edit link.

Comment: @MartinSmith this is 7 hours after the initial edit (which was not done through the app) and is still happening now after multiple refreshes app restarts etc.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288734/145673 which you have already commented on.

Comment: Not sure that is related, my issue is limited to the app (I get the correct revision on the site). I can't seem to reproduce on any other improved edits (mine or otherwise) either so either something messed up with the revisions by chance or something else is going on.

Comment: Well it seems related in that both issues are about insufficiently distinguishing between individual revisions in an improvement pair.